# Trace mount(2) and unmount(2) callers on the system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to debug an issue where an NFS share is auto-unmounted.
I am suspecting systemd is the one which is doing a lazy umount but needs to be sure.
Is there a way to know which process called mount(2)/umount(2) for a particular mount point?

Comment: Looks like inotify can throw IN_UNMOUNT event, not sure if we can get the process-id/name which did the umount.

Comment: You can do this through `auditd`, check [`man auditctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) (or just Google a bit).

Comment: [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/) or [lttng](https://lttng.org) or [`perf trace`](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Tracepoints) may help too. Sysdig is easy to use (it is like global strace), but both sysdig and lttng require installing additional kernel modules. What is your OS and kernel version?